# Range Validator in Excel with custom message text

Tags: c#, excel, validation, vsto, customization

I have the following code to give a Excel cell Validation with custom text.

```
var cellValues = activeSheet.Range[columnLetterValue + startingRow, Type.Missing];
cellValues.Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateCustom, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, cellValues.Value2, Type.Missing);
cellValues.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
cellValues.Validation.ErrorTitle = "Custom error title";
cellValues.Validation.ErrorMessage = "Custom error message description";
cellValues.Validation.ShowError = true;
cellValues.Validation.ShowInput = false;
```

When debugging the line to set the ErrorTitle or ErrorMessage a `'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'` is thrown.

Stacktrace:

> {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC):   Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC    at
>   System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName,
>   BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData&
>   msgData)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Validation.set_ErrorTitle(String )

I have looked online and found a couple of examples that show this is possible:
[Range Validation with Excel using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317307/range-validation-with-excel-using-c-sharp)

I've even recorded a Macro in Excel and it works with the "VBA" equivilent code:

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Custom"
    Range("A1").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertInformation, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="Custom"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = "UDF Title"
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = "The message"
        .ShowInput = False
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I've also tried different combinations of XlDVType and XlFormatConditionOperator but that didn't seem to make any difference in setting the custom messagebox text.

**Does anyone know how to set a Validation rule with custom ErrorTitle and ErrorMessage?**

Comment: This works for me in C# 2010 and Excel 2010.  I can run your code as shown above, with the only difference that I set CellValues to ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Range["A1"].  It adds the custom messages.  I can do things to make it fail on the long Validation.Add line, like having a blank in A1, but can't make it fail on either the error message or error title line.  One note, when you get it running you should probably include the Validation.Delete line, or you'll get runtime errors if you try to set it a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to setting a `Validation.ErrorTitle` to a range that didn't have a Validation rule.

Comment: Just a note that, as you probably know, it's nice when the sample code accurately reflects your actual code. Otherwise it can be a waste of time for somebody to try to debug (which I did for quite a while).   In your sample code `Validation.ErrorTitle`, the line generating the error, is set to "Custom error title," not to a range.

Comment: Sorry Doug it was me stripping it down enough to see the forest for the trees