# My (Good?) Method for making DropDown List in Excel programatically (VSTO)

Tags: c#, excel, drop-down-menu, vsto

Here is the method I wrote for making DropDown List in an Excel cell by taking the possible values from a range in the same sheet/workbook.

```
private void MakeDropDownList(string strSrcSheetName, string strDestSheetName, string strSrcRange, string strDestCell)
    {
        var currentSheet = Application.Sheets[strDestSheetName];

        var inv = Application.Sheets[strSrcSheetName];

        var items = inv.Range[strSrcRange];

        var list_items = new List<string>();

        foreach (Excel.Range cell in items)
        {
            list_items.Add(cell.Value2.ToString());
        }

        Range xlsRange;
        xlsRange = currentSheet.Range[strDestCell];

        Excel.DropDowns xlDropDowns;
        Excel.DropDown xlDropDown;
        xlDropDowns = ((Excel.DropDowns)(currentSheet.DropDowns(Missing.Value)));
        xlDropDown = xlDropDowns.Add((double)xlsRange.Left, (double)xlsRange.Top, (double)xlsRange.Width, (double)xlsRange.Height, true);

        //Add item into drop down list
        for (int i = 0; i < list_items.Count; i++)
        {
            xlDropDown.AddItem(list_items[i], i + 1);
        }
    }
```

To use it, I can invoke it like this:

```
MakeDropDownList("Units", "ReceiveBonds", "B1:B5", "E9:E18");
```

BUT, the final result is like this:

[image: Excel DropDown List]

As you can see, the DropDown List is smaller than the `E` Column Width, **and what's worse is that after I select a value from the DropDown List, the cell keep its original Value** which is `Choose Unit`.

Am I doing something wrong?

What I want:

- Either make this DropDown List look like the regular validation dropdown of Excel, Or.
- Be able to trigger an event to set the selected value from the list to the corresponding cell.

Comment: Unless you're opposed to actually using Excel's built in validation dropdowns... [this should point you in the write direction.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6069717/1316573)

Comment: @DanielCook On the line `cell.Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, values, missing);', I'm getting a COM Exception 0x800A03EC

Answer (score 0):

Just add  `ColumnWidth` before.

```
        if (checkModifiers() && (checkKey(Keys.F3)))
        {
            Workbook wb = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
            Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rng = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell;
            int row = rng.Row;
            int column = rng.Column;

            Range cell = ws.Cells[row, column];
            cell.ColumnWidth = 50;
            try
            {
                drd.Add("One");
                drd.Add("Two");
                drd.Add("Three");
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDown xlDropDown;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns xlDropDowns;
                xlDropDowns = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns)(ws.DropDowns(Missing.Value)));
                xlDropDown = xlDropDowns.Add((double)cell.Left, (double)cell.Top, (double)cell.Width, (double)cell.Height, true);
                for (int i = 0; i < drd.Count; i++)
                {
                    xlDropDown.AddItem(drd[i], i+1);
                }
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```