# How to use .net to add checkboxes to an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: .net, excel, openxml, closedxml

I have carefully researched this and not found the answer, yet.

I received a task that required me to export some tabular data to Excel in .net.  I was pleasantly surprised to find the "ClosedXML" library that does most of what I want with relative ease.  However, when I sent my work to my client, he said that he would like for each row of data to have a checkbox next to it.  The idea is that the user can check and uncheck the boxes, upload the file to a web server, and then have the web server make changes to a database based on which boxes are checked.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any reference to checkboxes in ClosedXML, and I saw at least one comment in a discussion somewhere saying (without any further explanation) that ClosedXML doesn't do checkboxes.

I tried creating an Excel spreadsheet and putting nothing on it except for a single checkbox.  I tried browsing the OpenXML object model and found that there seems to be the following reference to the checkbox:

`document.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.Single().ControlPropertiesParts.Single().FormControlProperties`

Yeah, all that to find a single checkbox, much less consider adding one for every row!

If I have code that is writing rows of data in Excel, how can I add checkboxes to the rows?  If I have to use a different library, that's okay.

**Update:** As @Mike suggested, it is easy to set this up as a drop down menu where the user can pick from two different options using data validation.  The code looks like this:

```
cell.SetValue(item.isOn ? "On" : "Off");
cell.DataValidation.List("\"On,Off\"", true);
```

Comment: I dare say that your customer is about to choose an unsuitable tool for what they need to accomplish. Excel is not a GUI for simulating data input dialog boxes... it's about spreadsheets containing tabular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `ClosedXML`, but I think I understand your client's intent.

Instead of offering checkboxes, you could create a blank column that the client can type an 'X' in. You could even use [data validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6069717/772086) to allow the user to pick the 'X' from a drop-down menu.

Comment: Although this does not technically answer my question, it definitely provides a good way to accomplish what my client wants.